# Displaying IP Cam Feed in MATLAB GUI

Tags: matlab

I am trying to display an IP Camera live feed in a MATLAB GUI. I am using the MATLAB IPCam Addon. I can successfully preview the live feed in MATLAB as follows:

```
cam = ipcam('url');
preview(cam);
```

However, I am unable to get the live feed in a GUI Axes. I was able to get a snapshot to display by adding the following code to the OpeningFcn of my GUI.

```
cam = ipcam('http://192.168.43.1:8080/video'); hImage=image(snapshot(cam),'Parent',handles.axes2);
```

However, when I replace the `snapshot(cam)` with `preview(cam)` to get a live feed instead of a single static snapshot, I get an error

> the data type of image is invalid

Comment: Can you run `cam=ipcam('url');` and `img = snapshot(cam);` and then call `whos im` and *edit your question* to include the output?

Answer (score 0):

The `preview` function does not apply to `ipcam` objects. Instead, its preview is a sub object that you should call, try the below instead:

```
cam = ipcam('url');
cam.preview;
```

Furthermore, the URL to stream live feed varies with the ipcam used. In my case, the URL is: http://192.168.1.70/cgi-bin/hi3510/mjpegstream.cgi?-chn=11&-usr=admin&-pwd=admin

I found a small list of functions here: https://www.instar.com/faq_cgi_hd

Hope this helps.